# java read specific lines from file

Tags: java, string, file, text

I have a huge txt file with repeating sections, starting from HouseName and finishing to RentPrice like in the text below:

```
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:04:04s] [startedRetrieving]getHouseName: house1
[04:04:04s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:04:04s] [startedRetrieving]price (in doll) [min: 1000, max: 1200]
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]squaremtr (in doll) [min: 75, max:85]
[04:04:04s] [startedRetrieving]sellVal (in doll) [min: 1000, max: 1200]
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]rentPrice(in doll) [min: 150, max: 200]
[04:06:04s] [startedRetrieving]getHouseName: house2
[04:06:04s] [startedRetrieving]price(in doll) [min: 1004, max 1100]
[04:06:04s] [startedRetrieving]squaremtr(in doll) [min: 85, max 99]
[04:06:04s] [startedRetrieving]sellVal(in doll) [min: 950, max: 1050]
[04:06:04s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:06:04s] [startedRetrieving]rentPrice(in doll) [min: 150, max: 290]
[04:09:04s] [startedRetrieving]getHouseName: house3
[04:09:04s] [startedRetrieving]price(in doll) [min: 1099, max: 1200]
[04:09:04s] [startedRetrieving]squaremtr(in doll) [min: 90, max: 110]
[04:09:04s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:09:04s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:09:04s] [startedRetrieving]sellVal(in doll) [min: 1100, max: 1300]
[04:09:04s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:09:04s] [startedRetrieving]rentPrice(in doll) [min: 199, max: 300]
```

Now, using a Scanner method I'm reading line by line and I would like to append into a String the lines for every room. For instance:

```
[04:04:04s] [startedRetrieving]getHouseName: house1
[04:04:04s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:04:04s] [startedRetrieving]price (in doll) [min: 1000, max: 1200]
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]squaremtr (in doll) [min: 75, max:85]
[04:04:04s] [startedRetrieving]sellVal (in doll) [min: 1000, max: 1200]
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]rentPrice(in doll) [min: 150, max: 200]
```

In this way for every string I could parse the values using my specific regexes and retrieve the values. Here's the code I'm using:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("path//to//file", "UTF-8"));
String string = "";
while(scan.hasNextLine()){
String str = scan.nextLine();
while(str.startsWith("getHouseName" && str.endsWith("rentPrice")){
string = string.append(str);
}
System.out.println(string);
}
```

But I'm getting an empty value. How can I save all the lines fromt he file specific to every house?
Thank you very much

EDIT: thanks to the response, I managed to have everything retrieved. How can I separate the group? Right now I have:

```
[04:04:04s] [startedRetrieving]getHouseName: house1
[04:04:04s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:04:04s] [startedRetrieving]price (in doll) [min: 1000, max: 1200]
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]squaremtr (in doll) [min: 75, max:85]
[04:04:04s] [startedRetrieving]sellVal (in doll) [min: 1000, max: 1200]
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]rentPrice(in doll) [min: 150, max: 200]

[04:04:04s] [startedRetrieving]getHouseName: house2
[04:04:04s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:04:04s] [startedRetrieving]price (in doll) [min: 1000, max: 1200]
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]squaremtr (in doll) [min: 75, max:85]
[04:04:04s] [startedRetrieving]sellVal (in doll) [min: 1000, max: 1200]
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]rentPrice(in doll) [min: 150, max: 200]

[04:04:04s] [startedRetrieving]getHouseName: house3
[04:04:04s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:04:04s] [startedRetrieving]price (in doll) [min: 1000, max: 1200]
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]squaremtr (in doll) [min: 75, max:85]
[04:04:04s] [startedRetrieving]sellVal (in doll) [min: 1000, max: 1200]
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]rentPrice(in doll) [min: 150, max: 200]

[04:04:04s] [startedRetrieving]getHouseName: house4
[04:04:04s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:04:04s] [startedRetrieving]price (in doll) [min: 1000, max: 1200]
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]squaremtr (in doll) [min: 75, max:85]
[04:04:04s] [startedRetrieving]sellVal (in doll) [min: 1000, max: 1200]
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]rentPrice(in doll) [min: 150, max: 200]
```

but I would like to print everything separate in a for loop. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
String string = "";
while(scan.hasNextLine()){
    String str = scan.nextLine();
    if (str.contains("getHouseName")) {
        string = "";
    }
    string = string + str + System.lineSeparator();
    if (str.contains("rentPrice")) {
        System.out.println(string);
        string = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But this is printing the whole file and ends with the RentPrice. Is it possible to print just the sections of each house?

Comment: @thranduil90 `string` contains all info of one house. If you remove `+ System.lineSeparator()` it will be clear in the printout.

Comment: How can I make a for loop in order to print, every time, a house and its values?